# specify root password with no-interactive mode into bash script

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-16.04, packer

I already done to specify root password when I create the vagrant box with Packer and Ubuntu 14, dealing with this command into script provisionning : `echo "root:vagrant"|chpasswd`

But I want to do this with new vagrant box based on Ubuntu 16.04. Unfortunately this command don't run and I must connect into my VM with SSH and specify manually my password root with : `sudo passwd`

**I don't want this step configuration password. How can I do that with packer and provisionning script sh ? Specify root password with no-interactive mode ?**

Comment: In theory that should work on 16.0 too. Have you tried setting/unsetting `ssh_pty`? The simple solution is just to set the password I your _preseed_ file or with _preseed_ arms in `boot_command`.

Comment: What is ssh_pty, how add this in preseed.cfg, what is preseed arms or how add this to the boot_command in json template file packer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

1) Set it in your `preseed.cfg` file with:

```
d-i passwd/root-password-again password vagrant
d-i passwd/root-password password vagrant
```

See [bento: Debian 8 - Example](https://github.com/chef/bento/blob/1c23471c104aedfa952405a00d10298826da02a5/http/debian-8/preseed.cfg#L26-L27)

2) Or set it as a preseed argument in `boot_command`:

```
"passwd/root-password={{ user `root_password` }} ",
"passwd/root-password-again={{ user `root_password` }} ",
```

Where `root_password` is a Packer *user variable*. See [boxcutter/ubuntu: Ubuntu Template](https://github.com/boxcutter/ubuntu/blob/master/ubuntu.json#L16-L17) (in this example the password for the `vagrant` user is set, not `root`)

---

**PTY**: See [Wikipedia: Pseudoterminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal) and [Packer Documentation: SSH PTY](https://www.packer.io/docs/templates/communicator.html#ssh_pty)

Comment: Very good accurate and complete response which run perfectly on windows 10 pro + packer 1.0.0 + Vagrant 1.9.3 and Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS